# Very quiet audio samples from AVCaptureMultiCamSession after disconnecting Lightning earphones

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avfoundation, audio-recording

I've encountered an issue with some AVFoundation video and audio capture code that only happens when changing `AVCaptureSession()` to `AVCaptureMultiCamSession()` with no other code changes.

It only reproduces intermittently, and the steps are:

1. Boot the app and capture session with no external mic connected
2. Connect a pair of Apple Lightning earphones
3. Start recording video and audio - the audio comes from the mic on the Lightning earphones as expected
4. Unplug the Apple Lightning earphones
5. The mic input switches to a built-in mic on the device, however the average power level on the audio samples coming in via `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` is now much quieter by about 25-30 dB.

This graph illustrates what's observed looking at the values of `AVCaptureAudioChannel.averagePowerLevel` from inside `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate.captureOutput(AVCaptureOutput, didOutput: CMSampleBuffer, from: AVCaptureConnection)`:

[image: Change in average power level]

The issue only reproduces intermittently, i.e. sometimes after unplugging the Lightning earphones the level coming from the built-in mic is completely normal. This issue only occurs when instantiating an `AVCaptureMultiCamSession` instead of an `AVCaptureSession`, the rest of the code is unchanged.

There is no handling of changes to the audio routing in the app. It's using the default audio device so the switch to the built-in mic is all being handled by AVFoundation. The code for setting up the audio capture is:

```
guard let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio) else {
    fatalError("could not create default audio device")
}
let audioIn = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)
if self.session.canAddInput(audioIn) {
    self.session.addInput(audioIn)
}
let audioOut = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
let audioCaptureQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.test.capturepipeline.audio", attributes: [])
audioOut.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: audioCaptureQueue)
if self.session.canAddOutput(audioOut) {
    self.session.addOutput(audioOut)
}
self.audioConnection = audioOut.connection(with: .audio)
if let aSettings = audioOut.recommendedAudioSettingsForAssetWriter(writingTo: .mov) {
    self.audioCompressionSettings = aSettings as? [String: Any]
}
```

One theory is that this is a bug with audio beamforming that AVFoundation is configuring internally. It's strange how the audio is still there but is just very quiet. Maybe AVFoundation's weighted processing of audio samples from the multiple built-in microphones done for beamforming is somehow missing some audio data, resulting in a very quiet final signal?

Perhaps someone else has encountered similar sorts of problems with `AVCaptureMultiCamSession`? It's new in iOS 13 and is only supported on fairly recent hardware.

Any ideas?

Thanks!